# Regex for matching email addresses

Tags: python, regex

So I have a regex that goes like:

```
 regex1= re.compile(r'\S+@\S+')
```

This works perfectly but I am trying to add a character limit so the total amount of characters have to be less than 20.

I tried `re.compile(r'\S+@\S+{5,20}')` but it keeps giving me an error. Seems like a simple fix, but cant see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That syntax is not to limit the total length of the string, it can't be applied after some other repeat modifier (?, *, +).

Comment: To do it properly is not easy given all possible variants, take a look at django implementation of email validation, it uses RegEx, https://git.io/fpxnn

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify a greedy modifier (`+`) with a specific number of characters (i.e., `\S+{5,20)` is not a valid pattern).  If you're doing this in python, I'd suggest just using the `len(...)` function on the string in addition to the regex to verify.  For example:

```
if regex1.match(email) and (len(email) < 20):
    ...
```